# show full file path in helm-buffers-list and helm-mini

Tags: helm, buffers

I'd like to show the full file path (if available) for Buffers in helm-buffers-list and helm-mini, just like it shows in the Recentf section of helm-mini.

How can I do this?

The reason is that I often filter by segments of the file path to find the buffer I want to open.

Comment: You can use `C-]`  that cal "toggle details". It will show buffer full path. But unable to narrow them based on path string. If you had problem with multiple buffer with the same name, try uniqufy.